# Superset: Jinja: Query based on filter value

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

I would like to run different queries based on Superset filter value. I tried:

```
{%- if filter_values('marketplace') == 'LOOKUP' -%}
QUERY
{%- endif -%}
```

But it did not work. What should I do and is It even possible?